# How does Lotus Notes databases store forms?

Tags: database, forms, extract, lotus-notes

How does Lotus Notes databases store forms? Is it part of the NSF file or a separate File? If it is in the NSF file, how do I access it? I have the Lotus Notes 7 client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lotus Notes stores all design elements, including forms, in the NSF file.  Using Domino Designer, you can edit the forms and other design elements.  Design elements are also like Notes documents, with UNIDs.